# Insert rows which are missing from tableB from tableA in oracle PL\SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I wanted to insert rows into tableB which are missing in table A
when i have written the below code on oracle it throws an error "ORA-00913: too many values
00913. 00000 -  "too many values"

Please suggest me the correct syntax:

```
insert into tableB 
Select * from 
(Select * 
from tableA A
left join tableB B
on a.id = B.id
and a.year = b.year
where (a.id is null or a.year is null) )A;
```

Comment: Syntax is ok, check that columns you are selecting in the query are the same that columns of `tableB`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISNULL condition need to be on the tableB's column and you need to select only tableA column values.

```
insert into tableB 
Select * from 
(Select A.* 
from tableA A
left join tableB B
on a.id = B.id
and a.year = b.year
where (b.id is null or b.year is null) )A;
```